# Can I promote base class to child class?

Tags: c++, superclass, base-class

I have a class A, as below:

```
struct MY_DATA
{
    int m_nType;

    union
    {
        DWORD m_dwBData;
        double m_dCData;
    } u;
};

class CClassA
{
public:
    CClassA(BYTE* lpData, UINT uSize);
    virtual ~CClassA(void);

    MY_DATA m_Data;
};

CClassA::CClassA(BYTE* lpData, UINT uSize)
{
    ::memcpy(&m_Data, lpData, uSize);
}

CClassA::~CClassA(void)
{
}
```

and a class B derived from class A, as below:

```
class CClassB : public CClassA
{
public:
    CClassB(BYTE* lpData, UINT uSize);
    virtual ~CClassB(void);

    void ProcessBData()
    {
        m_Data.u.m_dwBData ++;
    }
};

CClassB::CClassB(BYTE* lpData, UINT uSize)
: CClassA(lpData, uSize)
{
}

CClassB::~CClassB(void)
{
}
```

Then I recieve a memory block lpData with size of uSize. uSize is same as the size of MY_DATA. But I don't know m_nType in advance.

**My purpose is to determine the type of the memory block and invoke the corresponding processing function to process the data follows the type.**

So I do that in the following code snippet:

```
    CClassA a(lpData, uSize);

    if (a.m_Data.m_nType == 0)
    {
        CClassB& b = (CClassB&)a;
        b.ProcessBData();
    }
```

I will create an instance of Class A by using a memory block, then if the type of the data is 0, then we will know the data is of class B, then I will promote the oriignal instance to its child class ClassB so that we can invoke ProcessBData to process the data specific to class B.

However, I doubt if this will work, since class B is a child class of A, so it will contain more entries than class A, by prmoting a base class to its child class, will that cause problem?

Another solution is create a new instance of Class B after knowing the type is 0, with the same memory block. However, this will decrease the performance, since we copy the memory block twice, once to class A and once to class B.

So how to solve such a delimma?

Thanks

Comment: Definitely do not cast a base class to a child class if it is not actually the child class. To me it seems that the decision for which class to instantiate should be handled by a factory function based on the data at hand.

Comment: Why don't you simply implement some move semantics? Or if the old object has to be kept in order, make the other class not being a child but instead storing a pointer to the first class.

Comment: I also do think a pointer would be the right way to go. What about factory to create an object which contains the pointer.

Comment: Your code snippet contains udefined bahavior. It might appears to works in some case with some compiler but it would fails in other cases. It would definitively be very dangerous if `ClassB` would have additionnal data member.

Comment: From "Writing the perfect question" https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ > `One trap that many posters fall into is to ask how to achieve some “small” aim, but never say what the larger aim is.` So what is your goal? What are `lpData` and `uSize`, and how do you use them? How do you initialize `m_Data`? Why do you need inheritance in this case? Without this info there is no **dilemma**, because it's unclear what the options are.

Comment: @x00, Thank you for your comment. I have revised the post to include all the necessary info.

Comment: So, basically, you want to invoke different processing functions based on the value of the first integer stored in a memory block which comes from some other code? And that memory block contains a tagged union, so what you really want is to process the right field of the tagged union?

Comment: @IgorG, correctly. The actual code is much more complex, but the basic idea is same, based on the type of the data, do further processes.

Comment: 1. Is there a reason why you need a class for that task? Would a single processing function do the job?
2. Is it possible to use `std::variant<>` instead of `MY_DATA` struct? Or is that struct fixed, with no chance to change it?

Comment: @IgorG, originally I put all codes for m_dwBData and m_dData, i.e., codes in CClassB and CClassC into CClassA. But that is not ideal so I try to refactor the codes and use CClassB to process m_dwBData and CClassC to process m_dCData.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot get the type information at runtime, without adding/getting any type of information about the content of the data. There are some solutions if you can get type information somehow

1. Either you set `struct MY_DATA::m_nType` befor processing it by getting it's type by looking at the data (maybe you have some kind of identifier inside your data, specific value ranges for a specific type, different size for different data types).
2. Documentation gives you some information of what kind of information you will receive
3. You can change the declaration of `MY_DATA` and use [Runtime Type information](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)

**Solution 1:**
In case of DWORD and double you could for example use the size of the data

```
std::cout << sizeof(unsigned int) << std::endl;
>> 4
std::cout << sizeof(bouble) << std::endl;
>> 8
```

if you have acces to the original creation of data.

**Solution 2:**
Well, apparently look at your documentation or ask the developer who provided the data.

**Solution 3:**
Use [Runtime Type information](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) for your `MY_DATA` struct. This could  look as following:

myclass.h

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>

struct MY_DATA{
  virtual ~MY_DATA() {};
};

struct MY_DATA_B : public MY_DATA{
    unsigned int data;
};

struct MY_DATA_C : public MY_DATA{
    double data;
};

class CClassB {
public:
    CClassB(MY_DATA* lpData);
    virtual ~CClassB(void);

    void myMethodB();

private:
  MY_DATA_B* m_Data;
};

class CClassC {
public:
    CClassC(MY_DATA* lpData);
    virtual ~CClassC(void);

    void myMethodC();

private:
  MY_DATA_C* m_Data;
};
```

myclass.cpp

```
#include "myclass.h"

#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

CClassB::CClassB(MY_DATA* lpData){
  m_Data = new MY_DATA_B;
  memcpy(m_Data, lpData, sizeof(MY_DATA_B));
}

CClassB::~CClassB(){
  delete m_Data;
}

void CClassB::myMethodB(){
  std::cout << "MY_DATA_B data: " <<  m_Data->data << std::endl;
}

CClassC::CClassC(MY_DATA* lpData){
  m_Data = new MY_DATA_C;
  memcpy(m_Data, lpData, sizeof(MY_DATA_C));
}

CClassC::~CClassC(){
  delete m_Data;
}

void CClassC::myMethodC(){
  std::cout << "MY_DATA_C data: " << m_Data->data << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "myclass.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>


void execute(MY_DATA * ptr){
  if(typeid(*ptr) == typeid(MY_DATA_B)){
    CClassB a(ptr);
    a.myMethodB();
  }else if(typeid(*ptr) == typeid(MY_DATA_C)){
    CClassC a(ptr);
    a.myMethodC();
  }
}

int main(){
  MY_DATA_B b;
  b.data = 5;
  MY_DATA_C c;
  c.data = 3.1;

  MY_DATA * ptr = &b;
  MY_DATA * ptr2 = &c;

  execute(ptr);
  execute(ptr2);
  
  return 0;
}
```

This will result in the following output:

```
MY_DATA_B data: 5
MY_DATA_C data: 3.1
```

If you really just get a bunch of memory without any further information about it's content and want to get the type of the information => Then your design is broken beyond repair.

Comment: Actually I use the pointer advice in the comment. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of challenging to figure out exactly what you are trying to do... as far as I know if you try to cast from a base class up to a derived class, this could be ill-formed and potentially lead to U.B. or undesirable defined behavior... It's really hard to tell because it depends on the context it'll be used in, corner cases, etc...

Here's a possible proposed structure that may help you... It uses polymorphic inheritance through a combination of template specialization and a CRTP structure. It might look something like this:

```
template<class T, int type>
class Data {
protected:
    Data() {};
public:
    virtual ~Data() {}
};

template<class T>
class Data<T, 0> {
protected:
    DWORD data;
};

template<class T>
class Data<T, 1> {
protected:
    double data;
};

template<typename T, int type>
class Base : public Data<T, type> {
protected:
    Base() {}
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void processData() {}
};

class ClassA : public Base<ClassA, 0> {
public:
    ClassA(const BYTE* lpData, UINT size) {
        ::memcpy( &(this->data), lpData, size);
    }

    void processData() override {
        return;
    }
};

class ClassB : public Base<ClassB, 1> {
public:
    ClassB(const BYTE* lpData, UINT size) {
        ::memcpy( &(this->data), lpData, size);
    }

    void processData() override {
        data++;
    }
};
```